# Prove $\nabla(u\nabla w)=<\nabla u,\nabla w>+u\Delta w$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $\nabla(u\nabla w)=<\nabla u,\nabla w>+u\Delta w$

**My attempt:**

By definition:

$\nabla(u\nabla w)=\nabla u\nabla w+u\nabla^2w \implies \nabla (u \nabla w)=\nabla u\nabla w+u\Delta w$

Here i'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: what is your setting?

Comment: sorry, u,v: $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ @Riquelme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $\nabla$ I assume you mean $\mathrm{Div}$. We have that:
$$
\mathrm{Div}(u \nabla v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\right) 
$$
Because the components of $u\nabla v$ are given by $(u \partial_{x_1}v, \cdots , u \partial_{x_n}v)$.
Applying the product rule to each component, we obtain:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\right)= \frac{\partial u}{\partial  x_i}\frac{\partial v }{\partial x_i } + u\frac{\partial^2 v }{\partial x_i^2} 
$$
Summing over $i$, this becomes:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial  x_i}\frac{\partial v }{\partial x_i } + u\frac{\partial^2 v }{\partial x_i^2} \right]= \langle \nabla u , \nabla v\rangle + u \Delta v 
$$
Where angle brackets denotes the standard dot product. This can be called the "product rule" for divergence of a vector field times a scalar function

Comment: Oh, okay then you say $\nabla u . \nabla v=\langle \nabla u , \nabla v\rangle$ ?

Comment: Yes, $\langle \nabla u , \nabla v \rangle$ is the same as $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$